# Friendly URL for all languages, using preg_match

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

I'm developing a function, that will rewrite all strings into a friendly looking URL. 100% of the answers I saw on this topic were using the English alphabet ONLY.

This is what I've done so far:

```
<?php
function CleanURL($string, $delimiter = '-') {
    // Remove special characters
    $string = preg_replace("/[~`{}.'\"\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\_\=\+\/\?\>\<\,\[\]\:\;\|\\\]/", "", $string);

    // Replace blank space with delimeter
    $string = preg_replace("/[\/_|+ -]+/", $delimiter, $string);

    return $string;
}

echo CleanURL('Testing special characters: !@#$%^&*()_+[];\'\,./{}:"|<>?'); // Returns Testing-special-characters-
echo '<br />';
echo CleanURL('Bulgarian: текстово съобщение'); // Bulgarian-текстово-съобщение
echo '<br />';
echo CleanURL('Chinese: 短信'); // Chinese-短信
echo '<br />';
?>
```

Can someone help me with the following:

1. Remove the last `-`, if there is one;
2. `strtolower()`, if possible;
3. Optimize the `preg_replace`, if possible;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.
You can try `trim($string,"-")`. It removes all dashes at both ends.

2.
When you work with multibyte characters you should use the mb_ functions. Using that you can use `mb_strtolower($string);`

3.
If you want to just remove non-word characters, maybe this will work for you: `preg_replace("/[^\p{L}]/ui","","Bulgarian: текстово съобщение");`

This becomes

```
function CleanURL($string, $delimiter = '-') {
    // Remove special characters
     $string = preg_replace("/[^\p{L}\/_|+ -]/ui","",$string);

    // Replace blank space with delimeter
    $string = preg_replace("/[\/_|+ -]+/", $delimiter, $string);

    // Trim delimiter
    $string =  trim($string,$delimiter);

    return mb_strtolower($string);
}
```

**UPDATE**

Here's the doc for the preg stuff I did, in case you'd like to tweak it:
http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php

And added your defined characters as legal characters, otherwise there's nothing to replace with delimiter, duh.

Comment: Hehe awesome, thanks a lot! Just one problem - the cyrillic (bulgarian) characters are returning as `�`, but it must be an encoding problem, I'll try to fix it.

Comment: `return mb_strtolower($string, 'UTF-8');` fixed it. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem! Yes, that's just an encoding problem, as you found out. You should probably add `mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");` and `ini_set("default_charset","UTF-8");` somewhere that's included in all your pages/scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Here how we do it in Production. Works great, try it out!

**EDIT** Just add more `$str=str_replace('','',$str);` if needed

**EDIT 2** Extend this class, or use this library from following link for support of most characters. I think its your best choice rather then convert everything to ascii first.

http://iamseanmurphy.com/creating-seo-friendly-urls-in-php-with-url-slug/

Call `Text_Slug::slugify($str_to_be_slugified);`

Call `Text_Slug::isSlugified($string);` for a quick check if string is slugified

```
class Text_Slug
    {
        public static function slugify($str)
        {
            $str=str_replace("é",'e',$str); //Special chars
            $str=str_replace("É",'E',$str); //Special chars
            $str=str_replace(' ','-',$str);
            $str=preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]/i","",$str);
            return strtolower($str);
        }

        //Check if its slugified.
        public static function isSlugified($string)
        {
            if(preg_match("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]/i", $string) > 0)
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but like I've said, it's for all alphabets, not only English. If I use your class, and the string is "това е пробно съобщение", it will return nothing.

Comment: So you basicly want something that is replacing and recognizing all characters from all different charsets and converts them to url-friendly form?

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the last -, if there is one;

```php
if (substr($string, -1) === '-') {
    $string = substr($string, 0, -1); // Remove last char
}
```

2. strtolower(), if possible;

```php
return mb_strtolower($string);
```

3. Optimize the preg_replace, if possible;

(Maybe I'll update later)

Now, we put it on together:

```php
function CleanURL($string, $delimiter = '-') {
    // Remove special characters
    $string = preg_replace("/[~`{}.'\"\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\_\=\+\/\?\>\<\,\[\]\:\;\|\\\]/", "", $string);

    // Replace blank space with delimeter
    $string = preg_replace("/[\/_|+ -]+/", $delimiter, $string);

    // Remove the last -, if there is one
    if (substr($string, -1) === '-') {
        $string = substr($string, 0, -1); // Remove last char
    }

    return mb_strtolower($string);
}
```

Comment: 1. Can it be done with the same `preg_replace`? There are 14,000 calls of this function each hour. 2. I think there is strtolower for non-English alphabet, I'll search for it now.

Comment: @TsvetanTorbov:

1. You can use this: `$string = preg_replace('/-$/', '', $string);`

But string functions is faster than regex functions.

Comment: @TsvetanTorbov 2. You can use `mb_strtolower()` to working with non-English alphabet characters.